# Problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, apache2, dpkg

Recently I upgraded Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 and then to 14.04.

Now I'm getting some weird problems:

1. When I boot my machine from the grub menu using the normal "Ubuntu" option, my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key starts blinking and I get "CALL TRACE" messages on the screen and then it freezes.

   So I boot using Advanced Options.
2. Under Advanced Options I have two Linux Kernels: one of them is linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic. which boots fine but when I try booting through the other kernel I have the same as problem 1 above.
3. My Apache2 is not starting. While booting itself it says apache2 "ERROR".
4. `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` when installing anything.
5. When I tried solutions mentioned here http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-985232.html I get the same as problem 3 above.
6. Sometimes I get this error: processing was halted because there were too many errors.

*How should I proceed?*

**Edit:** Output of `uname -a`

```
Linux abhishek-Inspiron-7520 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Edit:** Output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**Edit:** Output of `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

```
libpango-1.0-0:amd64 depends on fontconfig (>= 2.1.91); however:
Package fontconfig is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpango-1.0-0:i386:
 libpango-1.0-0:i386 depends on fontconfig (>= 2.1.91); however:
  Package fontconfig is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpango-1.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386:
 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.36.0); however:
  Package libpango-1.0-0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency proNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

etc etc, ...

dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
 libpango-1.0-0:amd64
 libpango-1.0-0:i386
 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386
 libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64
 libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64
 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
 libgtk-3-0:amd64
 libgnome-control-center1
 libnautilus-extension1a
 libpeas-1.0-0
 libunity-control-center1
 libgtk-3-bin
 librsvg2-2:i386
 librsvg2-2:amd64
 librsvg2-common:amd64
 librsvg2-common:i386
 gnome-icon-theme
 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
 deja-dup
 libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64
 gcr
 gnome-keyring
 libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64
 libgtk2.0-0:amd64
 libgtk2.0-0:i386
 libindicator7
 libappindicator1
 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64
 libindicator3-7
 libappindicator3-1
 libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64
 libatk-wrapper-java
 libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64
 libcanberra-gtk0:amd64
 gnome-session-canberra
 libcogl-pango15:amd64
 libclutter-1.0-0:amd64
 libclutter-gst-2.0-0:amd64
 gstreamer1.0-clutter
 gstreamer1.0-x:amd64
 libcheese7:amd64
 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:amd64
 libcheese-E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Too many questions in one. You should post each question separately so that others with that particular problem can benefit. I agree that this is far too broad to be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` gives an enormous amount of errors, I would do the following:

1. Take a full data back-up (/home, /usr, /var)
2. Take a full system backup ([Clone](http://clonezilla.org)) OR Insert an additional hard drive
3. Insert the Server CD, reboot from CD and reinstall (on the new hard drive)
4. Re-install all applications
5. Mount the old partitions
6. Copy/restore the data from the old partitions to the new install

Comment: Something not right? (accept has disappeared)

Comment: No it worked fine. I re-installed it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not resolve all the problems, but for Number 7, try to shutdown your Windows first. If you use Windows 8 or 8.1 try run `shutdown -s -t 0` to fully shut down the Windows

Comment: yeah i figured the solution of Problem 7. Its working. But others are still not solved

Comment: And that's the problem with adding too many problems into one question: multiple answers.  Please delete this answer as problem #7 will be removed later as it has nothing to do with the previous problem(s).